# drop down not selected - dont filter mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a combo of textbox search and drop down menu filtering.
How can I make that if nothing is selected (first options) mysql select command does not select that as value and dont filter anything down by that value?

```
select * from table where A like '$A' AND B='$B' AND C='$C'
```

Comment: how about constructing your sql by including only the values that should be searched/compared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query="select * from table where 1";

if(isset($A)&&!empty($A))
$query.=" AND A='".$A."'";

if(isset($B)&&!empty($B))
$query.=" AND B='".$B."'";

if(isset($C)&&!empty($C))
$query.=" AND C='".$C."'";

mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: This worked for me as a charm. Just needed a bit of editing, for example: after `A=;B=;C=;` you need to put `'` so its like `A='"` And instead of !empty($A) i used $A!=="firstoption"

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
$b = isset($_POST['b']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['b']) : 'b';
```

If the dropdown was selected and isn't default, then use that value in the query. If not, then simply make the query be `B=B`, which will always be true.

Comment: What I understand I just define $b like that and leave my query alone and it will do what I need? If that is the case then ok, but i got an erro `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'` in the lane where I put your code

Comment: woops. sorry. typo. the final `?` should be a `:`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: please mind your grammar a bit more when asking questions as I personally find your question a bit fuzzy and hard to understand.

But if I understand your question right, what you should do, and which is in my opinion the cleanest and most readable, is just check if anything is selected in your javascript or PHP code and use two select statements instead of one.

The first one being just a simple

```
SELECT * FROM table;
```

and the second one being the select statement which does filter.